# How can I know when an EditText loses focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, lostfocus

I need to catch when an `EditText` loses focus, I've searched other questions but I didn't find an answer.

I used `OnFocusChangeListener` like this

```
OnFocusChangeListener foco = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

But, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Implement `onFocusChange` of `setOnFocusChangeListener` and there's a boolean parameter for hasFocus. When this is false, you've lost focus to another control.

```
 EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 - but worth noting that if your edit text is in a listview, every key down will result in the box losing and getting focus. See this solution to keep track of the currently focused box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527067/android-edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-on-calling-notifydatachanged

Comment: Where do I add the code you show? If I put it as is in "onCreate" the app crashes

Comment: @Léon Pelletier The truth? Really? User touches another focusable control and the editText loses it. I can't see any problem. It's the same if you set the focus by your code.

Comment: @Jona You could add it anywhere but onCreate() works. If it crashes you do something wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Have your `Activity` implement `OnFocusChangeListener()` if you want a factorized use of this interface,
example:

```
public class Shops extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{
```

In your `OnCreate` you can add a listener for example:

```
editTextResearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
editTextMyWords.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
editTextPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

then android studio will prompt you to add the method from the interface, accept it...
it will be like:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  // todo your code here...
}
```

and as you've got a factorized code, you'll just have to do that:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if (!hasFocus){
    doSomethingWith(v);
  }
}
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin way

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (!hasFocus) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using Java 8 lambda expression:**

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
    if(!hasFocus) {
        String value = String.valueOf( editText.getText() );
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Its Working Properly**

```
EditText et_mobile= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

et_mobile.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            if (et_mobile.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                CommonMethod.showAlert("Please enter name", FeedbackSubmtActivity.this);
            }
        }
    }
});



public static void showAlert(String message, Activity context) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    try {
        builder.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```