# Add a character in an EditText

Tags: java, android

I need to add a character "S" right after the last written number in an EditText (Oe) so:

if i write i number : "123", it must send "123S" instead. If i write "1234", it must send "1234S" instead.

How to do that ?

my code:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_write_HRM_Noty)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            str = Oe.getText().toString();
            str = str.substring(0, 0) + "G" + str.substring(0, str.length());
            mService.enableHRNotification(mDevice, str);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Are you simply asking how to add a character to a string?  If so: `str+='S';` will work.  Then you simply add the string back to the EditText with `.setText(str)` or simply put it back into your notification with 'S' added (as Blundell suggested).

Answer (score 0):

```
 mService.enableHRNotification(mDevice, str + "S");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a new string including by putting together the `edittext` and the character you want to add `finalString = (string + "s")`. Then use the `setText()`method to change the contents shown in the `edittext`

2) You could do this directly after the user enters something in the text box (after it `loses focus` or they finish typing and go to the next field)

Check this thread out: [How can i know when a edittext lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-a-edittext-lost-focus)