# Android White Background when keyboard fades away

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Video of the problem from a different user but its the same

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jzov.jpg

I have a background image set as follows :

```
  .pane {
  background-image:  url("../img/inner-banner-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And in my config.xml

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
```

Now the problem I am having is when the keyboard fades away after I hit done / search, it leaves a white background for like 0.5 during the transition for the space the keyboard covered and it looks a bit bad.

When the keyboard closes it unshrinks but leaves white gap. How can I get the keyboard to not shrink the view behind the backdrop ?

When I set

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>
```

It doesn't happen. I am also using the Ionic Plugin Keyboard.

Anyway I can make the transition of the keyboard fading not display the white background ?

Edit : Here's my android settings

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And my config Settings

```
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false"/>
```

And in the Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android",
    "ios"
  ]
```

In my web view I use ion-view and ion-content

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content class="has-header has-tabs">
```

Comment: A potential workaround for the white background not disappearing is adding the following code where you want the keyboard to close, for example in an event handler for enter keystroke or submit form event. You also need to add `$ionicScrollDelegate` as a dependency.
`if (cordova) { cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close(); } $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView().resetScrollView()`

Comment: No joy, still get the jump in the page with white background

Comment: did you checked , the debugger goes to that line?

Comment: are you using any `<textarea>` in your form???

Comment: in Native android code, there is one flag "windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan" this can help if it's a android app. So if you can dig and look into source for what Android does with this flag you can convert that logic into yours.

Comment: It could be GPU rendering

Comment: I have tried going from 'adjustResize' to adjustPan and this does fix the problem however you lose the fact the content doesnt resize nicely to view the inputs etc, so this problem is related to adjustResize imo

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the problem and the layout file where it occurs?

Comment: I found this online from a guy with same problem http://imgur.com/ca2cNZv

Comment: To which `html` elements do you append your css classes? I have a quite similar set up with background image and fullscreen = false, but i cannot reproduce your problem...

Comment: which css classes do you mean, the background css ? Right now it's .pane

Comment: I just wanted to know wo which html element your `.pane` class is appendend. But I assume that you are using an `ion-pane` directive. Do you have any footer in your view?

Comment: Actually in my view I have <ion-view>
    <ion-content class="has-header has-tabs">

Comment: No footer but I have have tabs

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue or still facing the error?

Comment: Still facing the issue with current settings

Comment: @StevieB what about `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml file try to set `windowSoftInputMode` attribute to [**adjustNothing**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

It worked for my Ionic project, avoiding the resize of Cordova webview when soft keyboard is on.

Comment: Ok this does indeed fix the problem and the closest to a solution yet, the only down point being without the resize it's hard sometimes to see the input box but I guess thats the restriction of this choice

Comment: Damn it's soo nice to not the see the white background and the flicker but the fact there is no resize it means i can't see the buttons on my pop-ups sometimes so not a great user experience.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the white bkgrd on keyboard close is a Cordova webview issue which is too slow in resizing

Comment: I tried also with Crosswalk webview but with no appreciable improvement.

Comment: This makes the keyboard block some content and cannot be scolled to

Answer (score 2):

That is your `windowBackground` peeking through. You are probably drawing over the white background of your Theme with that teal background. Modify your theme to include a better background color and remove the background from your layout if possible to improve drawing performance.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="android:windowBackground">#ff000000</item>
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: Where abouts in Ionic does this go ?

Comment: I've never seen any styles.xml in a Cordova (or Ionic) project. I have a styles.xml in a Xwalk Plugin for Cordova but it's another thing...

Answer (score 2):

Put:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient</item>
</style>
```

In styles.xml
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548337/852842)

Comment: I don't see  styles xml anywhere in ionic project

Answer (score 1):

Its happen because window re size itself to make room for the soft input area

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
..
...
</activity>
```

Comment: wow, its working like a charm, thx

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is a simple workaround for this

you need to add overflow-scroll="false" to your ion-content this should fix it

```
<ion-content class="padding has-header has-footer" overflow-scroll="false">
```

related topic [Ionicforum](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4849)

Comment: Tried still happening, after the keyboard fades away which takes around 0.5 second theres a white background which takes up the space of they keyboard and then fades away.

Comment: Mh this is weird did you have a look at the forum post? some people said that using ion-scroll instead of ion-content worked for them the overflow-scroll worked for me since i had the same problem

Comment: Yup tried the ion-scroll aswell but didnt make a difference. Each time the keyboard closes I got that white background flicker.

Comment: are you using the default webview or crosswalk for your project, and what android version are you running?

Comment: Never heard of cross walk, is that somepart of Ionic ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103108/discussion-between-stackg91-and-stevieb).

Comment: Hey SevieB, Ionic fixed this bug, I just installed the 1.2.4 version of Ionic and there seems to be no white background anymore I could even remove my workaround everywhere and it is still working fine

Answer (score 0):

Open your **platform -> app ->src ->AndroidManifest.xml**

Edit

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

**To**

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Answer (score 0):

Doing this solved it for me:

I was trying to apply background to the login page of my app with selector 'app-login'.

I added a div inside the page and set its background to the image I wanted. But whenever I opened the keyboard, I had some part of the screen turned white just above the keyboard and white space left after the keyboard was closed.

Adding height: 100% or height: 100vh did not solve the issue. It solved on some devices but not in others.

DO THIS:
Instead of adding background to ion-content or div just go into your global CSS file and add:

```css
app-login{
  background-image: url("./assets/bg@2x.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Change the CSS selector to the selector of your page and change the url to your own image accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in your 'App.js'. add

```
$window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', function (event) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('native.keyboardhide', event);
});
```

when app.run() method call with $window and $rootScope dependency. also, add

```
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
```

in  $ionicPlatform.ready().

please ensure that your code is updated by inspecting your app. If it's not updated then try to remove and add platform and rebuild your app.

Comment: No effect still white background when the keyboard fades

Comment: This causes the keyboard to obscure the bottom area, elements are not visible underneath and cannot be scrolled to