# White screen when closing Android keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, keyboard, screen

I'm creating an hybrid application with WebView system and I have an issue with Android : when I tap on an input, the keyboard shows up, I write what I want and when the keyboard disappear, he leaves a white background that makes its size.

Here is a screeshot of the problem. First screen is when the keyboard is open and the second one is when the keyboard is closed.

[image: Keyboard opening]
[image: After closing the keyboard]

I did a lot of research and still haven't found a good solution...
I already haved seen [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201412/android-white-background-when-keyboard-fades-away) but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my MainActivity :

```
[Activity(
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
    LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan, 
    HardwareAccelerated = true
)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
```

And here my androidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="fr.beautiful.app" 
    android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="fr.edition.ftel.cosoft.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <application android:label="BeautifulApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
      android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
      android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I’ve tried almost every windowSoftInputMode but none seem to work.
Finally, the bug does not occur on all devices but only the most recent

Do you have any idea to help me ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your description, I can not reproduce your issue at my side, but I find this at github:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/3817,you can take a look firsyly, then if you still have this issue, I suggest you can create simple sample at github, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: I forgot to say that the bug does not occur on all devices but only the most recent...

Comment: I suggest you can feedback this issue at github to get more info.