# How to display toast when changing focus in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on a login page of an activity where I have username and password as 2 EditText boxes.
I am trying to display Toast message when focus is changed from username to password box :
-If the text entered in username box has whitespace in it.
-If no white space then no Toast display.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               if (txtEdit.getText().Contains(" ")) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627231/2111834

Answer (score 0):

You can use View.OnFocusChangeListener for this.

Code sample:

```
et_uname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     if (hasFocus == false && et_uname.getText().toString() != null && et_uname.getText().toString().contains(" ")){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                   
    }
  }
};
```

This is done for fragment. If inside Activity then you can replace

```
getActivity()
```

with

```
<activityname>.this
```

Here hasFocus = true means et_uname currently has focus and hasFocus = false means do not have focus. As you require to alert user when focus is lost, have to add a condition for hasFOcus == false.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement **[OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)** for both your edit, see the code below:

```
 EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);

 myEdit .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
           // Do the check for white spaces and display the Toast
        }
    }
});
```