# How can I detect if an Edittext loses focus?

Tags: android

I want to be able to detect when an edittext isn't clicked, so I can replace it with a textview. I tried

```
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!v.hasFocus()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOST FOCUS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

but the Toast message wouldn't get called.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-a-edittext-lost-focus

Comment: You have !v.hasFocus(); Try just !hasFocus.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the boolean var that is supplied:

```
if (!hasFocus){

}
```

When you get the callback, it could be that the view still has focus, so `v.hasFocus()` might return true.

Comment: I tried this but it still wont call the Toast message when I click out of the edittext

Comment: You should show a little more of your code in that case, because otherwise it seems fine.