# How to check if EditText still has error message on clicking submit button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a Sign-Up form.

I have used `setError()` to set error messages in all `EditText` s. now I want to check that whether an `EditText` has error message or not when I click on the submit button.

Comment: When i click on submit button i want to check if the Email field has error field or not.  If it has error message then form can not be submitted

Comment: where are you setting the error in EditText?

Comment: if the correct format of email is not entered then it will display an error message

Comment: and you are checking for correct format on click of submit. am I right?

Answer (score 6):

To check text after it has been written but before clicking register/submit button on your page, you need to use `TextWatcher`

After setting up error with `setError()`, you need to check if `getError()` returns `null` as well as `editText.getText().length()` returns `0` then perform action like `Toast` or anything.

E.g:

```
onClick(View v){
    if(editText.getError() != null || editText.getText().length() == 0){
        ................(Perform Toast or something for clearing error)
    }else{
        .... your action to perform on button click
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [getError()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getError()) method for the `EditText` and check if it returns `null`. Although a better way would be to just set a boolean `isValid` on errors and check against that

Answer (score 1):

Right approach to achieve an error less submission of your form will be following:

1. on click of submit check whether entered text is a correct email.
2. if its not correct show error using `setError`.
3. if its correct go ahead and submit your form.

you need not to check explicitly if error is set or not as upon next submit field will be re-verified anyways.

Comment: actually my objective is to display the errors after the typing but before the submit button is pressed

Comment: you [can use `onFocusChange`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10627231/1529129) to achieve that. still it is a good idea to keep validation on submit button.