# Make EditBoxes not related to each other

Tags: android, android-layout, editbox

I want to make each EditText separated from the others.

But when I select the first EditText it shows the next EditText instead of submit or confirm then goes to the next EditText and so on.

Here is the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ommabdelhafiz.amathmess.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">











            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="×"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/first_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:hint="Ans"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:id="@+id/first_ans"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/first_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/first_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>






            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="49"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/second_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="÷"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/second_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:hint="Ans"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:id="@+id/second_ans"/>









                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/second_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/second_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>









            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="711"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/third_1st"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="×"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:id="@+id/third_2nd"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:hint="Ans"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:id="@+id/third_ans"/>








                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/third_true_ans"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/third_false_ans"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>









        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to process the data after editing then this link may be of use [How can i know when a edittext lost focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-a-edittext-lost-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` or `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` on your first edit text. By default, when you don't specify anything and there is a next edit text, Android will set `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` so you need to override this default.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer and well done explaining what is going on. Keep it up!!!