# Change background color of edittext if it is filled with input

Tags: android

I want to change the background color of `EditText` when it is filled with input I tried for if focused I want to change for if filled also

I tried with `android:state_focused` it is working if focused it is giving yellow background now I want same thing to happen when it is filled.

[This is the image here second box which is focused having yellow background and first box filled but not having yellow background I want filled box also should have yellow background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E3qJ.jpg)

If focus state background color changing if filled then same should happen.

Comment: you can try TextWatcher() for editText and try to change background color in onTextChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextWatcher to understand if your edittext is filled with text, then change its color if text length is > 0.

In kotlin:

```kotlin
yourEt.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                when (p0?.length) {
                    0 -> yourEt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
                    else -> yourEt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFCB"))
                }

            }
        })
```

In java:

```java
yourEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {     
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (editable.length()>0){
                //chnage the edittext background color if filled
                yourEt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFCB"))
            }else {
                //chnage the edittext background color if not filled
                yourEt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnTextChanged of edittext like below:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {     
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if (editable.length()>0){
                //chnage the edittext background color if filled
            }else {
                //chnage the edittext background color if not filled
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I don’t now how it works in android. But if you try to check on lostfocus if text box length > 0 then text box background color = yellow.

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-an-edittext-loses-focus