# Kotlin - How to know if editText lost focus

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app I need to be able to catch if an `editText` lost focus, I've found how to do it in java but I'm not quite able to find how to do it in kotlin.

The Java answer I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-an-edittext-loses-focus/10627231):

```
 EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me convert this to kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way

```
// Class level
lateinit var editText: EditText


// Method onCreate/onCreateView
editText = findViewById(R.id.whatever)


editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
    if(!hasFocus) {

    }
}
```