# Doing calculation in android edtitext on lostfocus

Tags: android, math, android-edittext, lost-focus

I'm writing an app the is does a lot of calculating and I'd like to accomplish some calc when I leave an `EditText`. Nothing fancy, things like entering 7/16 and having 0.4375 as the result or 1.0259 * 7 and having 7.1813 as the result. The function wouldn't be used all the time but would eliminate a couple of steps when needed.

Thanks   Steve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know when an EditText loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-an-edittext-loses-focus)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the wrong question, but the comment posted got me thinking, needed to look at substrings.
I've figured out what I need.