# setOnFocusChangeListener called for all EditText when focus changed for one of them

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've added two rows with EditText in RecyclerView.

In onBindViewHolder:

```
row.inputField.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
    // print object identifier
}
```

But when I touch on the second EditText, setOnFocusChangeListener called twice for first and second view with **b=true**.

Why does it work like this?
It's the problem on Android >5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android edittext in listview loses focus on calling notifydatachanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527067/android-edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-on-calling-notifydatachanged)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu thank you for your answers. I haven't problems when used listview, only with recyclerview. And I can't set currentlyFocusedRow because user can set focus for first edittext again.

Comment: You need a listener for each row, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151979/how-to-add-onclick-listener-to-recycler-view

Comment: @Vedant onClick don't work for EditText and don't work for itemView when EditText above it.