# Room - Saving edits in a list to database design question

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a list of restaurant menu items.

1. Burger
2. Fries
3. Pepsi

A user can edit any of the menu items and change the string

1. Cheese Burger
2. Cheese Fries
3. Diet pepsi

The user can hit the save button to save all the edits.
My question is what is if there is a better way than what I'm doing currently.

Right now when ever a user starts typing or anything, such as adding even a single letter "Burgerz", I would save that into a instance variable Map with the position of the item thats changing as the key, so 0, Burgerz. If he adds another "z", I would put it into the map as 0, Burgerzz.

When the user hits the save button, I would loop through the entire map and then make Updates to my local SQLite database

"UPDATE menu_item WHERE id = 0"

If the user has 30 edits to the menu, it would loop through the map and make 30 Update queries.

This is the only way I could think of, I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this?

Comment: What if you send the update when the editText looses focus? it would be an update per item and you won't be lopping anything

Comment: what do you mean by "won't be looping anything"? The textChangeListener doesn't affect my SQL query.

Comment: You said "it would loop through the map", if you use the focus listener you won't need a map var

Comment: If I don't have a map, how would I track the menu items the user has updated? If I have 100 items on the menu and the user updates 30 of them, the 30 inside the map would be the ones I would need to update in my SQLite db. I'm not understanding how a focus listener has anything to do with this? or Is there something I'm missing

Comment: Each editText would have a setOnFocusListener() -> if (!hasFocus)  -> update() . With that every time the et losses focus after the user enters another et or presses another view, etc. you would have on your db the value that has the et, That's another way as you asked.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, I wanted to save them all at the same time with a button click in the toolbar, but this works too. Can you create a quick answer so I can mark yours as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use `setOnFocusChangeListener` on every `EditText`

```
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            update(id)
        }
    }
});
```

**Important**:

> If your edit text is in a listview, every key down will result in the
> box losing and getting focus. See this solution to keep track of the
> currently focused box:

[Android edittext in listview loses focus on calling notifydatachanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527067/android-edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-on-calling-notifydatachanged)